# Forming columns from array elements present in json in a generic manner

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, mariadb

I am trying to create a table that would easily let me insert large data in json format.
So in a table with a json column i have inserted something like this:

```
{
 "Date": "25/9", 
 "Variables":["bc1", "gnp1","lt2", "m12", "ab1", "rad", "rnc1", "s1u_1", "sgsn_1", "sm21", "tt_1", "vlr_1", "voi", "volw2"], 
 "Value":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
}
```

I want to form columns present in Variables and for a particular entry their values will be present in the values array.

I have tried different json formats but in other ways i have to change the structure of my json and the problem that i need to overcome is to writing every column name in function such as json_value.
I need to overcome select `json_value(jsondata,'$.bc1) bc1,....`,
Here i can create custom bc1 column and its value will be there in $.bc1.

So the above fetch query can only be used in a json structure which as something like `{"bc1":"0", "gnp1":"2", .....}`, and then i have to write every key name to fetch their respective value.

I need a way to prevent writing every key name to create the columns. Thats why i created the json structure on top.

I need the result for the json in top in such way :

> Date  bc1 gnp1 lt2 m12 ab1 rad rnc1 s1u_1 sgsn_1 sm21 tt_1 vlr_1 voi volw2
>   25/9  0    0        0       0     0          0          0            0      0    0      0   0      0       0

[image]